# How to write a .htaccess rule to redirect a url to another server if there's 404 error in current server for the url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have a situation where I have done an upgrade for my content site and the upgraded site has a new DB while using the old site's domain.

That is I have a site.com (new version, new db) and old.site.com (old db).

So there are links that point to site.com/content which are now not available under site.com which will return a 404 while old.site.com will return content.

How do I rewrite and redirect the url from site.com/content-xyz to old.site.com/content-xyz if there's a 404 returned at site.com?

Comment: Is the url on site.com handled by a catch-all page? Ala wordpress where whatever url you enter is handled by index.php from wordpress? Or in other words: Is the 404 error served from Apache or from a framework you are using?

Comment: Good question. I just investigated and found Apache handles document requests not found with a htaccess rule ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Apache handles the serving of the 404 document, then that means we are hopefully able to redirect all requests to files that does not exist to the old domain. The downside is that this will even happen if the resource does not exist on the old domain either.

First make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled. Then add the following rule below any other rule you have on the new site.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ http://old.site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This will redirect all requests that do not ask for an existing file (`!-f`) or an existing directory (`!-d`) to the same url on the old site. If you have any other rules, you should put this under them, because the other rules might rewrite a fancy url to an existing page, and we don't want this redirect to happen in that case.

---

If the 404 is handled by some framework instead, for example for wordpress, then the request is already passed to a page that handles the request. Php, or whatever other language you are using, cannot pass that request back to Apache to do something with it. You would need to change files in that framework to let them do what you want them to do, and fear any upgrades that can undo your work.

Comment: This works perfectly for my case. I understood what you mean when you say if the application handles the 404 error generation which is not the case for me. Thanks for the solution!